# Android asynctask for max time

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, boolean

I'm trying to read data from a physical device.
For acquiring data I use an asynctask to avoid UI blocking.
When I click a button, I should do twice these (for min and max values):
wait 5 seconds;
acquire data for 1 second.
So the code is written in the OnClickListener of the button.
For the first task I use this method:

```
    new android.os.CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  }
          public void onFinish() {     }
    }.start();
```

For the second I'm using an asynctask and in its doInBackground method I have

```
while(booleanValueMax || booleanValueMin) {
   //code
}
```

(booleanValueMax and booleanValueMin are volatile boolean). Now I set these two to false using a Timer (outside the asynctask):

```
Timer min = new Timer();    
min.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        booleanValueMin = false;      
    }
}, 1000);
```

(same for max)

Now I'd like to use the same asynctask to store max and min values. So I know which data I'm acquiring checking the booleans (in the doInBackground method).

```
if(booleanValueMax)
   //store max
else
   //store min
```

The problem is that these variables are always false. And I don't know why.

Isn't there any other way to accomplish my goal instead of use Timer, CountDownTimer, etc.?I'

Comment: Post your complete code.seems like simple timings issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make two separate `asynchtask` and call them according to your value i.e.
    while(booleanValueMax || booleanValueMin) {
       //code
    }

Comment: maybe that's not the most elegant way but it works and it's fast for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the code that starts your asynctask, but: all asynctasks share the same thread pool. In the simplest case, it is just one thread. Most likely, your asynctask starts and finishes before any of the variables is set. Asynctasks are intended for long operations that do not need to wait. If you want your code to wait for an event, better use a `Thread`. (Well, it is possible to post messages/runnables to threads, see `Looper` and `Handler`.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
private void executeBigTask(){
    BigTask bigTask = new BigTask();
    bigTask.execute();

    // Check
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (bigTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
                bigTask.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }, 10000);
}


protected class BigTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        /**
        LONG TASK
        */

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.task_too_long), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```